# when i try to create storage gateway in AS using terraform, i face "error: retrieving activation key from ip address making http request timeout"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-storage-gateway

Please refer my script below, this worked fine earlier and now it times out when retrieving activation key. All the resources will be created except gateway.

Security group code is deleted as i am unable to post my question,
ports allowed in inboud - 445,159,139,80,22 and all ports in icmp
outbound - all ports

```
data "aws_ami" "latest_ami" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["*aws-storage-gateway*"]
  }

  owners = ["amazon"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "file_gateway_instance" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.latest_ami.id
  instance_type = "m5.xlarge"
  key_name      = var.keypair_name
  subnet_id     = var.subnet_id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.file_gateway_sg.id]
  user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    # Install file gateway
    curl https://filesystems-manager-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install.sh | sudo bash
  EOF

   tags = {
      Name = "file_gateway"
   }
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "domain_creds" {
  name            = "/secrets/ad/admin-password"
  with_decryption = true
}

resource "aws_storagegateway_gateway" "file_gateway" {
  gateway_name       = var.gateway_name
  gateway_timezone   = "GMT"
  gateway_type       = "FILE_S3"
  gateway_ip_address = aws_instance.file_gateway_instance.private_ip
  smb_active_directory_settings {
    domain_name = var.domain_name
    username = "admin"
    password = data.aws_ssm_parameter.domain_creds.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I think might happen here is that file_gateway_instance is in a subnet that does not have internet access.

From your subnet I assume it is a private subnet as you are not setting a public IP for the instance. If so, make sure you either have a NAT gateway setup in that subnet with the route 0.0.0.0/0

You can debug this by enabling VPC flowlogs and then filtering on the ENI of the EC2 instance and see if the outbound traffic is allowed (might also be NACL of the subnet blocking the traffic).

Comment: thanks for the response, we have NAT gateway setup in subnet with route 0.0.0.0/0 but still the issue persist

Comment: Also NACL is configured to allow all traffic

Comment: Can you add the VPC flow logs of the ENI so we can see if the communication outside the instance is happening properly? This allows us to see where the traffic is being blocked!

Comment: Also, maybe there is a mistake in your post but the port for SSL is 443 not 445!

Comment: 2 695059679865 eni-0b41a39afc8e02339 x.x.22.235 x.x.25.27 123 123 17 1 76 1687941152 1687941176 ACCEPT OK
2 695059679865 eni-0b41a39afc8e02339 13.40.94.30 x.x.22.235 123 123 17 1 76 1687941152 1687941176 ACCEPT OK
2 695059679865 eni-0b41a39afc8e02339 x.x.22.235 13.40.94.30 123 123 17 1 76 1687941152 1687941176 ACCEPT OK

Comment: i have tried with 443 as well

Comment: Check if you are using the right URL, this URL does not work: https://filesystems-manager-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install.sh - where have you found this URL? Because it gives the error "The specified bucket does not exist"

Comment: looks like this is the issue... do you have any active link for this?

Comment: removed the userdata and it is working now.. thank you

Comment: Great work! Indeed, if you use the AMI like you are using right now the activation with the storage gateway should be automatic. Have a great day!